# getting more than one items from local storage using javscript

Tags: javascript

I am currently working on a project and struggling to implement Local Storages on my work.

**About My Project:**

- I am trying to do a basic **FILM LIST Project**.
- I have 3 inputs. I saved them but I am not able to get all items from storage when the "DOMContentLoaded" listener run.
- I created a LocalStorage class and imported it to my app.js
- I created a FILM class and imported it to my app.js
- I created a UI class and imported it to my app.js

I am going to post my important functions and classes for you to check,

---

**Film.js**

```
class Film {
    constructor(title, director, url) {
        this.title = title;
        this.director = director;
        this.url = url;
    }
}
```

export default Film;

**UI.js**

```
class UI {
constructor() {

}

static addFilmToUI(film) {

    //console.log(film.title, film.director, film.url)

    let html = ` <tr>
                <td><img src="${film.url}" class="img-fluid img-thumbnail"></td>
                <td>${film.title}</td>
                <td>${film.director}</td>
                <td><a href="#" id="delete-film" class="btn btn-danger">Delete Film</a></td>
              </tr>`

    document.getElementById("films").innerHTML += html;
} ...
```

---

**LocalStorage.js**

```
class LStorage {
constructor() {

}

static getAllItemsFromLocalStorage() {

    let films;

    if (localStorage.getItem("films") === null) {
        films = [];
    } else {
        films = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("films"));
        console.log(films)
    }
    return films;

}




static addItemsToLocalStorage(film) {

    let films = this.getAllItemsFromLocalStorage();
   
    films.push(film);
  
    localStorage.setItem("films",JSON.stringify(films));
}}
```

---

**App.js**

```
    const form = document.querySelector("form");
    form.addEventListener("submit", createFilm);
    document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded",function(){
    let films = LS.getAllItemsFromLocalStorage();

    Array.prototype.forEach.call(films,(element)=>{
        UI.addFilmToUI(element)
    })
})

function createFilm(e) {
    e.preventDefault()
    const title = document.getElementById("title");
    const director = document.getElementById("director");
    const url = document.getElementById("url");

    let informations = [title.value, director.value, url.value];

    if (informations.every((values) => values != "")) {
        const createdFilm = new FILM(title.value, director.value, url.value);
        UI.addFilmToUI(createdFilm);
        LS.addItemsToLocalStorage([title.value,director.value,url.value]);
    } else{
       alert("Cant be empty!")
    }
    UI.clearInputs(title,director,url)

}
```

- When I refresh my page the only thing I get is **undefined**.
- When i upload only film the console output is:

  ```
   [Array(3)]
  ```

  0: (3) ["Avatar", "James Cameron", "js.png"]
  length: 1
  **proto**: Array(0)

Comment: Don't write `UI` and `LStorage` as a class if it has no state, no members, an empty constructor, is never instantiated, and has only static methods. Just use a plain object literal to define a module.

Comment: I appreciate your informative and corrective comment. Thank you!

Comment: You haven't shown your `FILM` class, but notice that in `createFilm` you are invoking `addFilmToUI` with a `FILM` instance whereas in the `forEach` callback you are invoking `addFilmToUI` with an array of three values (like the one you passed to `addItemsToLocalStorage`). That array does not have `.title`, `.director` or `.url` properties.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ah, I found my mistake. I send multiple params to a single-valued param function also when I calling my data from storage, I did kind of override I guess. I tried to invoke my data from where I put them into UI. That's why I confused. Therefore I created one function more which called loadAllData().

- And also i adjust my eventListener function as well.

**- LS.addItemsToLocalStorage(createdFilm)**

```
    document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded",function(){
    let films = LS.getAllItemsFromLocalStorage();

    UI.loadAllItems(films)
    
})

static loadAllItems(films){

        const filmList = document.getElementById("films");

        films.forEach((film)=>{
            filmList.innerHTML += ` <tr>
            <td><img src="${film.url}" class="img-fluid img-thumbnail"></td>
            <td>${film.title}</td>
            <td>${film.director}</td>
            <td><a href="#" id="delete-film" class="btn btn-danger">Filmi Sil</a></td>
          </tr>`
        })
    }
```